# Could not read malformed PDF file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pypdf

I need to run this code snippet but I get an error that `PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file`

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def getResponse(url):
    response = requests.get(url)       
    return response

def getNumberOfPages(response):
    with BytesIO(response.content) as open_pdf_file:
        read_pdf = PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
        #if read_pdf.isEncrypted:
            #read_pdf.decrypt("")
        num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        return num_pages

responsenew = getResponse("http://www.reichelt.de/bilder/downloads//DSGVO/DSGVO_EN_2020.pdf")
print(getNumberOfPages(responsenew))
```

How can I fix this? I saw some other answers that talked about de-cryption but it didnt work for me.

Comment: wow it looks like the pdf is malformed because when I download it in local I cannot opened it

Comment: I could open it on my local computer though @AlbertFX91

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getvalue()` -> `open_pdf_file.getvalue()`

and this is code :

```
def getNumberOfPages(response):
    with BytesIO(response.content) as open_pdf_file:
        getcontent = open_pdf_file.getvalue()
        read_pdf = PdfFileReader(getcontent.decode("utf-8"))
        #if read_pdf.isEncrypted:
            #read_pdf.decrypt("")
        num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        return num_pages
```

Comment: Have you tried this snippet? Because I got this error ```gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed```

Comment: yes i have tried and get the response from server , but you should change only getNumberOfPages function to above code

Comment: Yeah, I changed it but now it gives me ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<!DOCTYPE html><html>```